Positiveness of sinc function integral
Is there a simple way to see that
$$ \int_{-a}^0 \int_0^a \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} \, dx \, dy \geq 0 $$
for all $a>0$?

If you view the integral as full space integral with $f=1_{[0,a]}$, $g=1_{[-a, 0]}$, the kernel is $K(x-y) = sinc(x-y)$, then it is $$\int f(x) \int K(x-y)g(y) dy dx$$ seems Plancherel theorem + Fourier transform under convolution may work? Does this count as "simple"?

How does this lead to the positivity? Doing as you say, we get (up to a constant) $\langle f, K \ast g\rangle = \langle \mathcal F f, 1_{[-1,1]} \mathcal F g \rangle$, but it's not immediately clear why this is positive, is it?

Too long for a comment
For $a\geqslant0$
$$\int_{-a}^0 \int_0^a \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} \, dx \, dy=\int_0^a \int_0^a \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} \, dx \, dy=\frac12\int_0^a \int_0^a  \left(\int_{-1}^1e^{it(x+y)}dt\right)dx \, dy$$
$$=\frac1{2i^2}\int_{-1}^1\frac{(e^{ita}-1)^2}{t^2}dt=2\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin^2\frac{at}2}{t^2}e^{iat}dt=4\int_0^1\frac{\sin^2\frac{at}2}{t^2}\cos(at)dt$$
$$=2\int_0^1\frac{(1-\cos(at))\cos(at)}{t^2}dt=2a\int_0^a\frac{\cos t-1+\frac12-\frac12\cos(2t)}{t^2}dt$$
$$=2a\Big(\int_0^a\frac{\cos t-1}{t^2}dt+\int_0^{2a}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}dt\Big)=2a\int_a^{2a}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}dt\geqslant0$$

Use change of variables
\begin{align*}
& x-y = u \\
& x+y = v \\
\end{align*}
this translates to
\begin{align*}
& x = \frac{u+v}{2} \\
& y = \frac{v-u}{2} \\
\end{align*}
that has Jacobian $\frac{1}{2}$, so the integral becomes
$$
I = \int_{-a}^{0}\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\sin{(x-y)}}{x-y} \ dx \ dy = \iint_{D} \frac{\sin{u}}{2u} \ dA
$$
Where $D$ is the square $[0,a]\times[-a,0]$ rotated by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and dilated by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, hence
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{0}^{2a}\int_{|u-a|-a}^{a-|u-a|} \frac{\sin{u}}{2u} \ dv \ du = \int_{0}^{2a} \frac{\sin{u}}{2u} (2a-2|u-a|) \ du = \int_{0}^{2a} \frac{\sin{u}}{u}(a - |u-a|) \ du \\
&= \int_{0}^{a} u\frac{\sin{u}}{u} \ du +\int_{a}^{2a} (2a-u)\frac{\sin{u}}{u} \ du \\ 
&= 1 - \cos{a} + 2a\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{\sin{u}}{u} \ du -(\cos{a}-\cos{2a}) \\
&= \cos{2a} -2\cos{a} +1 +2a\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{\sin{u}}{u} \ du = \cos{2a} -2\cos{a} +1 +2a\left(\frac{-\cos{u}}{u}\Biggr|_{a}^{2a} -\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{\cos{u}}{u^2} \ du\right) \ du \\
&= \cos{2a} -2\cos{a} +1 -\cos{2a} +2\cos{a} -2a\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{\cos{u}}{u^2} \ du = 1-2a\int_{a}^{2a}\frac{\cos{u}}{u^2} \ du \\ 
&\geq 1-2a\int_{a}^{2a} \frac{du}{u^2} = 1-2a\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{2a}\right) = 1-2+1 = 0.
\end{align*}
In the end I used $-\cos{u} \geq -1$ for every $u$ and that $a>0$.

why is $\int_a^{2a} \frac{\sin u}{u}\ge \int_a^{2a}\frac{du}{u}$?

@Yimin that's a mistake, sorry, I will try to correct it

@RaulFernandesHorta I think that your mistake is that $(a-|u-a|)$ is not equal to $2a$ for $a\leq u \leq 2a$, but $2a-u$.

@lasik43 you are right, thanks

@Yimin I think now it is correct

@RaulFernandesHorta yes, and all these answers are similar.

This might not be a simple way.
The integral is
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{[0, a]}(x) \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x - y) 1_{[-a, 0]}(y) dy $$
By Plancherel theorem,
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{1_{[0,a]}}(\zeta) \widehat{K}(\zeta) \widehat{1_{[-a, 0]}}(\zeta) d\zeta$$
The Fourier transform $\widehat{K}(\zeta) \ge 0$, the transform is the Rect function. And $\widehat{1_{[0,a]}}(\zeta) = \frac{e^{i\zeta a} - 1}{i\zeta}$ and $\widehat{1_{[-a, 0]}}(\zeta) = \frac{1 - e^{-i \zeta a}}{i\zeta}$, their product is $\frac{2-2\cos(\zeta a)}{\zeta^2}\ge 0$.

Simple enough, Svyatoslav's solution is similar and does not make use of Plancherel's theorem :)
